# React Router -- Differentiate goBack() and goForward() in listen()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

## Issue

With React Router v4, how do I differentiate between `goBack()` and `goForward()` calls with the `listen()` method?

As far as I can tell, the `location` and `action` parameters don't give enough info to distinguish. The `action` argument is `POP` for both back and forward.

```js
history.listen((location, action) => {
  // action = 'POP' when goBack() and goForward() are called.
}
```

I'm using the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) node module.

## Purpose

I have a breadcrumbs component whose items are held in state. When the user goes back, I need to pop the last breadcrumb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could collect all the `key` values from the `location` object in an array and use that to figure out if keys come before or after the previous one in order, and use that to distinguish between a `goBack` and `goForward`.

**Example**

```
const keys = [];
let previousKey;

history.listen((location, action) => {
  const { key } = location;

  // If there is no key, it was a goBack.
  if (key === undefined) {
    console.log('goBack')
    return;
  }

  // If it's an entirely new key, it was a goForward.
  // If it was neither of the above, you can compare the index 
  // of `key` to the previous key in your keys array.  
  if (!keys.includes(key)) {
    keys.push(key);
    console.log('goForward');
  } else if (keys.indexOf(key) < keys.indexOf(previousKey)) {
    console.log('goBack');
  } else {
    console.log('goForward');
  }

  previousKey = key;
});

history.push("/test");
history.push("/test/again");
setTimeout(() => history.goBack(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => history.goBack(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => history.goForward(), 3000);
```

Comment: You're a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Update for React Router Dom v6:

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClickHome = () => {
    navigate("/home");
  }
  const handleClickBack = () => {
    navigate(-1);
  }
  const handleClickForward = () => {
    navigate(1);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClickHome}>Go Home</button>
      <button onClick={handleClickBack}>Go Back</button>
      <button onClick={handleClickForward}>Go Forward</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```